# I want to learn implementation of twitter or other user based systems but how?

Tags: implementation

I want to learn implementation of twitter or other user based systems but how? My problem is, i know the language basics, i know the rules but when  i want to implement i don't know where to start. 
For example i'm coding a site which have 2 different user type: one of them normal user others are some advanced users. advanced users have more two links on their index page. I don't know how can do that.

I hope i can explain my problem.
Any help will be great for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend starting with a book on web development. A book such as [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition) will walk you through creating a basic application from start to finish.